# Find the index of an element in a fixed amount of time O(1)

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I'm trying to solve this question for an hour and just can't find any way to do so. 
The question is as follows:

A **sorted** list, length ***N***. There might be duplicates inside the list. 
Given an element `x`, you need to find the latest index of `x` in the list. 
If `x` does not exist, return a relevant message.

**Note:** The model is CREW (Concurrent Read Exclusive Write) - meaning concurrent read is allowed, but write is exclusive meaning concurrent write is **not** allowed.

1) Describe a parallel algorithm that uses ***N*** CPUs and solves the problem in a fixed amount of time (I guess they mean O(1)).

2) Explain why the algorithm described is correct.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because unlike the array where accessing the i-th element is O(1) for a list it is O(n).

Comment: If you have an array then each process reads its corresponding value from the array and if it is x then update an atomic variable if your id is higher than the current one (compareAndSet). You can initialize the value to -1 and so you know if there was an x found or not when all processes have finished.

Comment: But I don't know if that would be a solution, because if each value in the list is x then you have n processes waiting for each other to update the atomic variable, so I would still call it O(n).

Comment: @maraca, forgot to mention that the model is CREW (Concurrent Read - Exclusive Write) so I cannot update an atomic variable.

Comment: updating an atomic variable is a synchronized action, no concurrent writes

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need a for loop that will run in parallel and will check if Arr[i] = x. 
I cannot update any atomic variable inside the loop because it is concurrent write which is (unfortunately) not allowed here.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an OpenMP style solution not MPI. The update of an atomic variable is just an atomic (synchronzed) read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the input is a 0-indexed, sorted (increasing) array `A[]` of length `N`.

Initialise a shared result variable with the value `UNSET`:

```
RESULT := "UNSET"
```

Start `N` CPUs with the following program, parameterized by `i` (from `0` to `N-1`):

```
CPU(i):
if i==0 and A[0] > x {
    RESULT = "NO SOLUTION"
} else if A[i] == x and (i + 1 == N or A[i+1] > x) {
    RESULT = i
} else if A[i] < x and (i + 1 == N or A[i+1] > x) {
    RESULT = "NO SOLUTION"
}
```

The program has terminated when `RESULT` is updated.

Note that exactly one CPU writes to `RESULT` (because the input is sorted), so there's never a concurrent write, but each array location except the first is read by two CPUs. Each CPU does a fixed amount of work, so the program terminates in a fixed amount of time.

Comment: Note that although the array is listed, there might be duplicates in the array so this solution still does not resolve the concurrent write issue because there might be 2 CPUs writing to RESULT.

Comment: @SKriheli: Not obviously, can you give a counter-example? Only the CPU at the crossover point to the next value reports here due to the additional `A[i+1] > x` conditions, with instances straddling equal values keeping silent. At least I gather that that's the idea.